# Use of ! in VIM

Tags: vim, vi

I have seen that sometimes `:q` works but sometimes we have to use `:q!`. This is the case for many commands. I was wondering what is the general use of `!` in `vim` and when to use it. I tried to google this, but it seems the search is omitting the exclamation mark.

Comment: If you have vim installed on your computer, you should also have the interactive vim tutor. From the command-line (NOT from within vim) use `vimtutor`. It takes about half an hour and is the best way to learn the basics of vi/vim.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you make no changes to the actual content of the file, you can simply quit with `:q`. However if you make edits, vim will not allow a simple quit because you may not want to abandon those changes (especially if you've been in vim for a long time editing and use `:q` by accident). The `:q!` in this case is a force the quit operation (override the warning). You can issue a forced quit to all opened windows (such as those opened with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>) with `:qa!`.

You can write changes out and quit with `:wq` (or `:x`), and this sometimes will fail (the file has been opened as readonly (`-R` on the command line, or vim was invoked with the `view` command), in which case you can force the write operation with `:wq!`.

As an aside, you can also use `ZQ` to do the same operation as `:q!` and `ZZ` to do the same as `:wq`, which can be easier on the hands for typing :)

Vim also has a built-in help which you can access via `:help`; exiting has it's own quick topic page: `:help Q_wq`.

Comment: On a different note, you can also use `!` to run shell commands as in `:!ls -l`

Comment: how does ! in case of ':r! command' is it for forcing the output of command onto file

Comment: `:r! command` is very similar to `!!command`, the former will insert the command output on the following line following the cursor, the latter will replace the contents of the existing line.

Answer (score 5):

There is no "general use" of `!`, it's just a modifier. Each command gets to chose what an extra `!` will do to it.

In *many* cases commands are programmed so that `!` forces them. Examples include `q` that you mention, but also `save`: `save!` will overwrite the file if it already exists, while `save` would return an error and suggest to use `save!` if you are sure of what you're doing.

Finally `!` used on its own is used for shell commands, for instance `:!ls` or `:!mkdir foo`.

In the case of `read` (from your comment), the command `read! <something>` is interpreted by Vim as *"execute `<something>` and read (meaning, in Vim, write to buffer) its output"*. So here it is as if the `!` behaves not as a modifier of the `read` command but as the stand-alone command `!`. It could be that the `read` command does not declare a variant with `!` so Vim just interprets the rest independently (so it reads a "`!` used alone" after `read`), or that `read` declares a variant with `!` that has this particular behavior (*"execute the rest as shell"*) that happens to mimic what the "`!` used alone" does.

I guess the take-away is: there is not rule, each command defines what `!` will do, and while there is an attempt to have some sort of consistency in the effect of modifiers, not having super-strict rules (like *"`!` will **always** be for forcing"*) allow to have more useful behaviors with less keystrokes, which is a plus too.

Comment: ... also the annoying difference between `:w!cat` and `:w !cat`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers were very complete about `:wq!` use case, for example.

But the question was more open, about general use of `!`

For starters: **the name of `!` is "bang"**. Google search for "vim bang  linux" brings to this question, for example. (Interestingly, there is a "shebang", `#!`).

The bang is also used to issue bash commands from inside Vim, for example:

```
:!ls
```

Brings forth a bash shell, issues `ls` and displays output followed by "press ENTER to continue"; after pressing ENTER, the user returns to where he was inside Vim.

From this historical topic: [Great Vim shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim)

"`:` again puts me in command mode. `!` indicates that the content of the next yank should be piped through a command line."

From this you can notice that `!` does far more than just forcing exit with `:q!`!